# C# - Add glass button on toolstrip control?

Tags: c#, toolstrip

How do I add a `GlassButton` to a `ToolStrip` using C#. My code is:

```
ToolStrip toolStripTaskBar = new ToolStrip();
GlassButton gBtn = new GlassButton();
ToolStripButton button = (ToolStripButton)gBtn;
toolStripTaskBar.Items.Add(button);
```

I'm getting the following exception:

`Cannot convert type 'Glass.GlassButton' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton'`

Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem with above code

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ cannot convert type 'Glass.GlassButton' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton'

Comment: So, what is this Glass.GlassButton? Your own class, a third party class? If it's not a ToolStripButton, how do you expect to add it as if it were?

Comment: Whatever your GlassButton is if its not derived from a ToolStripItem it can't be on a ToolStrip.

Comment: Glass.GlassButton is third party class. I am using it to generate Glass Button. Now I want to add this button on toolstrip.

Comment: Skinning is done by the ToolStrip not the Items on the ToolStrip. So if you want a certain ToolStrip Look create a ToolStripRenderer thats will provide that look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223686.aspx) instead of ToolStripButton to add your custom button to the ToolStrip:

```
ToolStrip toolStripTaskBar = new ToolStrip();
GlassButton gBtn = new GlassButton();
ToolStripControlHost button = new ToolStripControlHost(gBtn);
toolStripTaskBar.Items.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to wrap your `GlassButton` is a `class` that bases `ToolStripItem`. The scope of issues you're going to run into with this is unknown and too broad for this forum.

The bottom line, a `GlassButton` is not, and does not base, `ToolStripItem` and that's why you're getting the error.